# How can i get textBlock from DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get text from textBlock in

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Name="dateCreateTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Path=DateCreate, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=TimeConverter }, ConverterParameter=DateCreate, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}}"  Background="{x:Null}"   Margin="3,6"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I searched something like

```
TextBlock tb = ((ContentPresenter)column.GetCellContent(row)).Content as TextBlock;
```

but it doesn`t work, i have tb = null;

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
TextBlock tb = (TextBlock )GridName.Rows[((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex].FindControl("dateCreateTextBlock");
```

Comment: Thank you, but have you something without FindControl, because i have about 20 textblocks

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.